# How to store and retrieve attributes of ComboBoxItem in xaml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, tags

I have a combobox with about 20 items. I want to associate up to 5 attributes with each ComboBoxItem such as color, price, shipping weight, etc.

I want to store all these attributes in the xaml file and retrieve them when item is selected in C# code.

How best do I do this? Is storing everything in Tag and parse the Tag string the best way? Thanks.

> ```
>  <ComboBoxItem Content="Shirt" Tag="Red;14;2"></ComboBoxItem>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store anything in the tag, if you want more type safetry create an object:

```
<ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
        <local:Attributes Color="Red" Min="2" Max="14"/>
    <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
<ComboBoxItem>
```

But even better yet you should not create the items on your own but just have an items collection and [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)/[data template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) it using the [`ComboBox.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx#Y6) and [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx), then you can store that with the item.

The `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will then directly be such an item with all the attributes you need.

Comment: Could you show me how to retrieve the Color attribute using your example? Right now I am using ...(comboBox1.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString() to retrieve the Tag's value. thanks.

Comment: @user763554: If the tag is such an object as shown above you just need to cast it, e.g. `var atts = ((Attributes)((ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Tag;` then you can just do something with `atts.Color`. (If you are new to XAML you might be interested in [that overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx) as well)